# JavaScript not removing text when a uppercase letter involved

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

So I have a text box on my website and I have coded this to prevent certain words from being used.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var banned = ['MMM', 'XXX'];

  document.getElementById('input_1_17').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('input_1_17').value;

    for (var x = 0; x < banned.length; x++) {
      if (text.toLowerCase().search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
        alert(banned[x] + ' is not allowed!');
      }

      var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);

      text = text.replace(regExp, '');
    }

    document.getElementById('input_1_17').value = text;
  }, false);
}
```

The code works perfectly and removes the text from the text box when all the letters typed are lowercase. The problem is when the text contained an uppercase letter it will give the error but the word will not be removed from the text box.

Comment: I suspect that converting text to lower case will never match values that are all uppercase.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are correct. another oversight. any suggestions?

Comment: Normally you should just make it all in lowercase, `text.toLowerCase().search(banned[x].toLowerCase())`.

Comment: Convert both? This really doesn’t seem too complicated, but perhaps I’m missing something,

Comment: I'm assuming in his real code, banned is already in lowercase, since it gives the `alert`. The issue comes from the regex, which does not match upper case characters in his text. If you put `/i` in the end it should ignore case

Comment: maybe if you add the case insensitive modifier to the regexp? 

var regExp = new RegExp( banned[x], 'i' );

Comment: Couldn't you add the 'ignore case' flag when creating the RegExp, i.e. `new RegExp(banned[x], 'i')`, to make the replace work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should use `.toLowerCase()` with both sides when comparing the `strings` so they can logically be matched.

But the problem actually comes from the Regex you are using, where you are ignoring **case sensitivity**, you just need to add **[the `i` flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags)** to it:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x], 'gi');
text = text.replace(regExp, '');
```

**Note:**

Note also that using an `alert()` in a loop is not recommended, you can change your logic to alert all the matched items in only one `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is a good direction, just you need some flags (to make it case-`i`nsensitive, and `g`lobal - so replace all occurrences):

```js
var text="Under the xxx\nUnder the XXx\nDarling it's MMM\nDown where it's mmM\nTake it from me";
console.log("Obscene:",text);
var banned=["XXX","MMM"];
banned.forEach(nastiness=>{
  text=text.replace(new RegExp(nastiness,"gi"),"");
});
console.log("Okay:",text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have been expecting something unreasonable. Lowercase strings will never match strings containing uppercase letters.

Either convert both for comparison or use lowercase banned strings. The former would be more reliable, taking future human error out of the process.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is actually convert both variables to either all caps or all lowercase.

```
if (text.toLowerCase().includes(banned[x].toLowerCase())) {
  alert(banned[x] + ' is not allowed!');
}
```

Not tested but it should work. No need to use `search` since you don't need the index anyway. using `includes` is cleaner. [includes docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)